# Disable clicking or typing in a WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using a WebBrowser control. I need to disable clicking or typing.

How do I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just purely disable WebBrowser controll I believe it supports enable disable function therefore you can read but you cant click or type

```
YouWebBrowserControllID.Enabled = false;
```

in other case try this

```
((Control)webBrowser1).Enabled = false;
```

Comment: webBrowser1 doesn't have an enabled method. I assume YouWebBrowserControlID meant webBrowser1 (or the name chosen for the WebBrowser control)

Comment: Great answer. I was trying to take screen shot every second and show that in picture box ! I get rid of that problem :) . thanks

Answer (score 6):

To just prevent users clicking on links, I set the `AllowNavigation` property to `False`.

Technically, users can still click on the links, they just don't do anything. After setting this property, updating the `DocumentText` property doesn't seem to work and you need to toggle the `AllowNavigation` on, set the html text and then toggle off.